# How to log bind variables on trigger after servererror

Tags: oracle, plsql, bind-variables

I need to track the value of bind variables to a query that returns an Oracle error.

Since the queries that return errors are not drawn in `v$sql_bind_capture` and `v$sqlarea`, I can't look at these tables.

Then I created a trigger after Servererror and logged the query in a trace table created by me. Unfortunately the bind variables are not traced (I read `:p0`, `:myVar`, etc...).

How can I do to track the value of these variables if I have not access to the session ?

Answer (score 0):

You can trace the session and set the `LEVEL` to capture bind variable values.

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context forever, level 4';
```

The different `LEVELs` of tracing event:-

```
0 – No trace. Like switching sql_trace off.

2 – The equivalent of regular sql_trace.

4 – The same as 2, but with the addition of bind variable values.

8 – The same as 2, but with the addition of wait events.

12 – The same as 2, but with both bind variable values and wait events.
```

Have a look at [How to generate trace file – SQL Trace and TKPROF in Oracle](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/how-to-generate-trace-file-sql-trace-and-tkprof-in-oracle/)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the session

Comment: You can ask your DBA or someone who could do this. Tracing the session would give you exact information.